# Should @white and @black be LESS variables?

Tags: css, less, agile

My colleague thinks that they aren't, but I would say that for consistency's sake having predefined variables for all common colours:

```
background: @backgroundBlue;
color: @white;
```

is more consistent than:

```
background: @backgroundBlue;
color: (white|#fff|rgb(255,255,255)|etc);
```

Please help settle this conflict.  Our working relationship is on the fritz...

Comment: Answers to this question will most likely be based on personal opinions mate. Hence I don't think this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: in my opinion, no they shouldn't. Every web dev should know #fff or #000. I see no need to make that a variable. I do however agree with your point of doing it for consistencies sake.

Comment: this is opinion based, so this not a very good stackoverflow question. i like defining colors in my templates. for example i want to know that my `yellow` is `#FFD717` and my `blueish` is `#39F` and then forget about the hex codes. For consistency, yes you should do that even for `white` `#fff`. Maybe a css guy decides to make `white` something like `#eee`. You are absolutely correct. You know even the earth itself changes, i wonder if google maps have in mind that the continents are moving. So, why `white` should always be `#fff`? :D

Comment: I'd rather use variables like `@main-heading-color` if needed so. `@white` should be always `white`; Don't you think so?

Comment: Using colour names in variables is generally frowned upon, because it is less semantic. You should use something that describes the element not it's colour. I have seen .blue-banner {background:red;} because the client was using colour names and then changed the colour on a whim. This is a good article: http://www.sitepoint.com/css-sass-styleguide/ the author actually uses a mixture.

Comment: I personally use $primaryColour, $secondaryColour, $tertiaryColour, and this will work across various projects.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should not define `@white` but rather a `@highlightcolor` or `@textcolor` variable incase you want to change the color from `white` to `lightgrey` for example